# Static colored attributes on custom types without adding them in class definition in python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance, static-typing

I would like to have a custom type whose attributes are highlighted statically in IDE (for auto-completion & error highlighting), e.g, VSCode, without explicitly adding them at class definition. For example:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Foo(NamedTuple):
    bar: int

class MyDict:
    def __init__(self, n: NamedTuple) -> None:
        self._n = n

    def __getattr__(self, key: str) -> int:
        return getattr(self._n, key)

foo = Foo(3)
bar = foo.bar  # `bar` is colored in Vscode

x = MyDict(foo)
y = x.bar  # `bar` is not colored in Vscode (no autocompletion either)
```

Is there a way to achieve this highlighting statically on custom types? Thanks.

Comment: You can't statically highlight something that is only decided at runtime.

Comment: Could it be possible to do by defining a generic? Like if the generic specified certain attributes, the concrete class has them as well?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: Can you give an example? I have been trying to get that to work without success. It works for the return types of a method, but not for the attributes of a class...

Comment: `class Generic:
    bar: int
class MyDict(Generic):`

Comment: No, what I meant was using `typing.Generic`, not class inheritance.

Comment: I think what I am asking is not possible... https://discuss.python.org/t/how-to-create-a-generic-type-where-the-output-is-the-inner-type/12993/3

Comment: I am trying to come up with something, but the code ends up just ugly, and I got stuck at what seems to be a bug in Pylance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255350/discussion-between-zranz-and-matszwecja).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a satisfying solution for my use case:

```
from typing import Generic, NamedTuple, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", bound=NamedTuple)

class Foo(NamedTuple):
    bar: int

class MyDict(Generic[T]):
    @property
    def inputs(self) -> T:
        ...

foo = Foo(3, 4)
bar = foo.bar  # `bar` is colored in Vscode

x = MyDict[Foo]()
x.inputs.bar  # `bar` is colored in Vscode
```

Not sure there is a way to accomplish this directly for `x.bar` though.